# secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm using `jsonwebtoken` to generate a bearer token.
Following the examples provided by the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) my code looks like this

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('src\\private.key'); //returns Buffer
let token = jwt.sign(myJsonContent, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
```

This code returns this error in console

> secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

I've tried including the key in my `.env` file but the error is the same
I've also tried to declare `privateKey`  as a `Buffer` but nothing changed.
Any solutions?

Comment: What is your local Node.js version?

Comment: @FilipSzymański v16.14.0

Comment: Can you please mention your OS version as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was an answer to this post but it got deleted so I'm answering to my question again.

My code looks like this:

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('src\\private.key', 'utf8');
let token = jwt.sign(myJsonContent, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
```

The problem I was having was related to the privateKey not being asymmetric.

The problem was that the key needed to be written in a correct `.PAM` format.

The `.PAM` format looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
encoded key etc
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Unless you already have a key, you will need to generate it,
and to do so I used `openssl`
You can download it [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openssl-for-windows/openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip)

Once you download it open the bin folder and execute the file named `"openssl.exe"`
At this point paste this command

```
genrsa -out privateKey.key 2048
```

This will generate a file called `privateKey.key` in the bin folder.
At this point you can either copy and paste the content of this file and use it as a key
or import the file in your project and use the readFileSync as I did.

This worked for me and fixed the problem I was having.


**If you already have a key** but you're having the same problem I suggest checking it with `openssl`.
You can find many useful commands [here](https://gist.github.com/Hakky54/b30418b25215ad7d18f978bc0b448d81) that might help you.

Comment: Generating the key with "traditional" switcht gave me the correct PAM format. The default operation leaves out the cipher type.

openssl genrsa -traditional -out private-key.pem 3072

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when I upgraded my `Ubuntu` from the `20.04.5` to the `22.04.2` version. It used to work well with the previous version. It seems that there is some system-related issue that occurs when we use it on `Ubuntu 22.04.2` with `Node 16.xx.xx`. It worked for me when I upgraded my Node.JS version from 16 to `Node.JS 18`.

Comment: There was a correct answer to this post but it was deleted. For me the issue was that the key had to be in a correct  .PAM format

Comment: @Synapsis I'm literally having this problem right now but no matter what I do, PAM format or otherwise, it is not working :/ anything else you could provide?

Comment: @Jridyard I posted the solution that worked for me, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

1. Open the key file in any editor and simply delete the new line chat at the end of your file.
2. Update the node version to current LTS *(I had the same issue, this worked for me)*

If you're using nvm, just try

- `nvm install 18.15.0`
- `nvm use 18.15.0`

You can specify the current LTS version of NODE. My case it was 18.15.0

Answer (score 0):

crypto.createPrivateKey function is used to create an asymmetric key instance from the private key

```
const privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey(privateKEY);
```

Comment: This function does not exist, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto as well as https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

This might be an AI-generated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar error while generating the keys on https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/ I later used crypto module and it worked fine. see the setup below

`````
import * as crypto from "crypto";

// Generate a key pair
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
  modulusLength: 2048,
  publicKeyEncoding: { type: "spki", format: "pem" },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: "pkcs8", format: "pem" },
});

console.log("Public Key:\n", publicKey);
console.log("Private Key:\n", privateKey);````
`````