# secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256: How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, jwt

So my code look like this.

```
const jwtPrivateKey = process.env.JWT_PRIVATE;

let signedJWT = jwt.sign(payload, jwtPrivateKey, {algorithm: "RS256"})
```

with an env file including

`JWT_PRIVATE=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEAQLdSMt......N/UiIUiWCxfESQ-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

I'm getting Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256 everytime I make a call.

How do I fix this?

I'm using Windows 10 and Node.js v18.16.1.

Tried first, second answer from
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75635389/secretorprivatekey-must-be-an-asymmetric-key-when-using-rs256\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75635389/secretorprivatekey-must-be-an-asymmetric-key-when-using-rs256%5C)

And upgraded Node.js version 16 -> 18.16.1 -> 20.3.1

Comment: The error is caused by `jwtPrivateKey`, can you show us the content of `.env`? If `jwtPrivateKey` contains sensitive information, can you create a new one for testing?

Comment: Which jwt library? There are dozens in npm, and probably hundreds more other places. And if you got a stacktrace include it.

Comment: I'm using jsonwebtoken library from npm.

Comment: https://rentry.co/n9wue Here it is @LinDu

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using an external rsa file generated by `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`

with
`const jwtPrivateKey = fs.readFileSync('./rsa.pem', 'utf8');`

Still I have no idea why this error happened.
Maybe there's something to do with indentation?